# How can I delete a user from sql server 2012 who owns a schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I created a new user in Sql Server 2012 and "by accident" I marked them as owner of multiple schemas. I meant to mark them as members of the schema but I was on the wrong tab!

Because they are now owners of the schema I can't unselect the ownership and I can't delete the user either. How can I undo my mistake?

[image: Schema Ownership]

Comment: `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_datareader TO [some_other_user];` (Also, this is why we write DDL scripts that we can validate, store in source control, etc. The only way to verify what you did pointing and clicking through a UI is to record some kind of screencast.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must transfer ownership of the schema to some other user, probably `dbo`, prior to removing the user:

To test this, I did the following:

Create a user to own the schema, and a test schema:

```
USE tempdb;
CREATE USER [testuser] WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [max] AUTHORIZATION testuser;
GO
```

Try to drop the user, which will fail:

```
DROP USER [testuser];
GO
```

> Msg 15138, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> The database principal owns a schema in the database, and cannot be dropped.

Transfer ownership of the schema to some other user, in this case the special user, `dbo`, which owns the database:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[max] TO dbo;
GO
```

Now, drop the test user, which works:

```
DROP USER [testuser];
```