# How to delete user logins and user defined schema's at once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-schema

I have some users in my database who are no longer part of the domain and I would like to know how would I delete these users and their user defined schemas at once, rather than having to manually do each one? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. SQL Server requires that if a user still owns any object you cannot drop the user. So the typical order is: 1) Transfer ownership of all the user's objects to someone else (sometimes to the DBO) 2) drop the user from the database(s). 3) Drop the user from the instance. If you skip 2 and 3 you will have orphan users which leads to very interesting problems.

Answer (score 0):

This should allow you to reassign the SCHEMA, DROP the SCHEMA then DROP the USER.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[schema name] TO dbo;
GO

DROP SCHEMA [schema name];
GO

DROP USER [user name];
GO
```

The script above is a modified version of a solution for a similar question *[How can I delete a user from sql server 2012 who owns a schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33026404/540756)*.